# Class View Composers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, view, composer-php

I have a `ServiceProvider` class

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CategoryListComposer::class, function ()
        {
            new CategoryListComposer($this->app->make(CategoryInterface::class));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->view->composer(
            'frontend.layouts.partials.header',
            $this->app->make(CategoryListComposer::class)
        );
    }
}
```

And `CategoryListComposer` class:

```
public function compose($view)
{
    dd(567);
}
```

When I run my application, the `567` can not printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've type-hinted the constructor dependency in your `CategoryListComposer` class, you don't need to do all of the binding in your `register` method.

Just remove the code from within the `register` method (Laravel requires that the method be present, even if it's unused), and change the `boot` method to this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->view->composer(
        'frontend.layouts.partials.header',
        CategoryListComposer::class
    );
}
```

Comment: so the body of register method is empty?